# USB 3.0 harddrive disconnecting

Tags: usb, mount, hard-drive

The external harddrive works under usb 2.0, but in usb 3.0 it mounts for a few seconds and then unmounts. I don't think it a problem with the drive because it works fine on usb 2.0.

dmesg reports this info

```
    [ 1010.527708] usb 2-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=2, Product=3, SerialNumber=1
[ 1010.527710] usb 2-2: Product: GoFlex Desk
[ 1010.527712] usb 2-2: Manufacturer: Seagate
[ 1010.527713] usb 2-2: SerialNumber: NA0LMM45
[ 1010.528178] usb-storage 2-2:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[ 1010.528399] scsi host56: usb-storage 2-2:1.0
[ 1011.526430] scsi 56:0:0:0: Direct-Access     Seagate  GoFlex Desk      0D18 PQ: 0 ANSI: 5
[ 1011.526763] sd 56:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg1 type 0
[ 1011.526955] sd 56:0:0:0: [sdb] 3907029167 512-byte logical blocks: (2.00 TB/1.81 TiB)
[ 1011.527282] sd 56:0:0:0: [sdb] Write Protect is off
[ 1011.527287] sd 56:0:0:0: [sdb] Mode Sense: 4f 00 00 00
[ 1011.527586] sd 56:0:0:0: [sdb] Write cache: disabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
[ 1011.531224]  sdb: sdb1
[ 1011.532484] sd 56:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI disk
[ 1013.029480] usb 2-2: reset SuperSpeed USB device number 57 using xhci_hcd
[ 1013.045858] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: xHCI xhci_drop_endpoint called with disabled ep ffff8800aee5a840
[ 1013.045862] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: xHCI xhci_drop_endpoint called with disabled ep ffff8800aee5a888
[ 1013.165353] usb 2-2: reset SuperSpeed USB device number 57 using xhci_hcd
[ 1013.181611] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: xHCI xhci_drop_endpoint called with disabled ep ffff8800aee5a840
[ 1013.181615] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: xHCI xhci_drop_endpoint called with disabled ep ffff8800aee5a888
[ 1013.301336] usb 2-2: reset SuperSpeed USB device number 57 using xhci_hcd
[ 1013.317893] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: xHCI xhci_drop_endpoint called with disabled ep ffff8800aee5a840
[ 1013.317898] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: xHCI xhci_drop_endpoint called with disabled ep ffff8800aee5a888
[ 1013.437271] usb 2-2: reset SuperSpeed USB device number 57 using xhci_hcd
[ 1013.453609] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: xHCI xhci_drop_endpoint called with disabled ep ffff8800aee5a840
[ 1013.453613] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: xHCI xhci_drop_endpoint called with disabled ep ffff8800aee5a888
[ 1013.573181] usb 2-2: reset SuperSpeed USB device number 57 using xhci_hcd
[ 1013.589439] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: xHCI xhci_drop_endpoint called with disabled ep ffff8800aee5a840
[ 1013.589443] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: xHCI xhci_drop_endpoint called with disabled ep ffff8800aee5a888
[ 1013.709092] usb 2-2: reset SuperSpeed USB device number 57 using xhci_hcd
[ 1013.725490] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: xHCI xhci_drop_endpoint called with disabled ep ffff8800aee5a840
[ 1013.725493] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: xHCI xhci_drop_endpoint called with disabled ep ffff8800aee5a888
[ 1013.725799] sd 56:0:0:0: [sdb] FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_ERROR driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[ 1013.725800] sd 56:0:0:0: [sdb] CDB: 
[ 1013.725801] Read(10): 28 00 16 e0 95 4f 00 00 40 00
[ 1013.725808] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdb, sector 383817039
```

Ubuntu occasionally pops up an error message:

```
Error mounting /dev/sdb1 at /media/colin/7607B44F50711B5C: Command-line `mount -t "ntfs" -o "uhelper=udisks2,nodev,nosuid,uid=1000,gid=1000,dmask=0077,fmask=0177" "/dev/sdb1" "/media/colin/7607B44F50711B5C"' exited with non-zero exit status 13: ntfs_attr_pread_i: ntfs_pread failed: Input/output error
Failed to read NTFS $Bitmap: Input/output error
NTFS is either inconsistent, or there is a hardware fault, or it's a
SoftRAID/FakeRAID hardware. In the first case run chkdsk /f on Windows
then reboot into Windows twice. The usage of the /f parameter is very
important! If the device is a SoftRAID/FakeRAID then first activate
it and mount a different device under the /dev/mapper/ directory, (e.g.
/dev/mapper/nvidia_eahaabcc1). Please see the 'dmraid' documentation
for more details.
```

Comment: Can you attach an `lspci` as well please?